# Remove empty First rows in PHPexcel

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin, phpexcel

I'm Uploading the excel file to the database on the website using phpexcel.
But first row is being skiped and entered my data.
The results is shown in the picture below.

i need a help..

How can I solve?

[image]

I have the following code.

```
<?
    include_once('./_common.php'); //database option 
    include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 
    include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; //load phpexcel

    $up_file = "aaa.xlsx";
    try {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($up_file);

        //set the read only
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

        //read a excel file
        $objExcel = $objReader->load($up_file);

        // select first cell
        $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objWorksheet = $objExcel->getActiveSheet();

        $rowIterator = $objWorksheet->getRowIterator();


        foreach ($rowIterator as $row) {
                   $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                   $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        }

        $maxRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $maxCell = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
         for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $maxRow; $i++) {

                 $acell = $objWorksheet->getCell('A' . $i)->getValue(); // A
                 $bcell = $objWorksheet->getCell('B' . $i)->getValue(); // B

                 $acell  = addslashes($acell);
                 $bcell  = addslashes($bcell);

              //$sql = "insert into echo_test (a,b,c,d,e) values ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e')";
                $sql = "insert into echo_excel set 
                bcat = '$acell',
                scat = '$bcell',

              ";
              sql_query($sql);
          }
       echo $maxRow . " Data inserting finished !";



    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo 'error!';
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply test the `$bcat` variable to see if it is empty before trying to insert data into your table.

```
$acell = $objWorksheet->getCell('A' . $i)->getValue(); // A
$bcell = $objWorksheet->getCell('B' . $i)->getValue(); // B

if (empty($bcell)) {continue;}  // no value for bcat so go to the next row

$acell  = addslashes($acell);
$bcell  = addslashes($bcell);
```